# Why do I get the error that body is a child of div in React project?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, material-ui, syntax-error, create-react-app

## **Mystery Error**

I'm finding it difficult to find the cause of an error I've been getting in my React project. It is complaining that `<body>` cannot appear as a child of `<div>` Here is the error message:

[image: Error message]

## **Possible cause #1**

I've searched the project for references to "body" and wondered if it was because I have a template.html that contains a `<body>` tag...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <titleMyWebsite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="modal"></div>
    <script>
      if (window.MSCompatibleInfo != null) {
        let text =
          "This site uses modern technology that your browser doesn't support, please use Google Chrome";
        alert(text);
        throw new Error('IE is not allowed please use Chrome!');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

...which is in addition to the webpack.config.template where it appears that body is being injected?

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  inject: 'body',
  filename: './index.html',
  template: './template.html',
  meta: {
    version,
  },
}),
```

I have tried to integrate a project that was set up with create react app with another type that doesn't use that. Could that be the cause? Sorry, I'm not very familiar with this!

## **Possible cause #2**

As well as this I also have a reference to body in my Material UI drawer. It uses this code:
https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#responsive-drawer

Inside that code you will see this line and it is located within a file called MasterLayout.js:

```
 const container = window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;
```

I don't know what this does?

I suppose there could well be other causes! But these are my primary suspects at the moment. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix/identify the cause?

Many thanks,

Katie

## **Edit**

I think this error is occurring in the following code as this is ListItemText:

```
const ContentList = ({ listHeader, data }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const classes = useStyles(theme);
  return (
    <>
      <Box boxShadow={Constants.widget.elevation} className={classes.box}>
        <List className={classes.listContainer}>
          {/* Header */}
          {listHeader && (
            <ListItem className={classes.listHeader}>
              <ListItemAvatar>
                <Avatar variant="square" />
              </ListItemAvatar>
              <ListItemText disableTypography primary={<Typography type="h3">Title</Typography>} />
            </ListItem>
          )}
          {/* List */}
          {data.map((content, index) => {
            return (
              <ListItem button divider dense component={Link} to="/" className={classes.listItem}>
                <ListItemText
                  primaryTypographyProps={{ variant: 'h5', component: 'h2' }}
                  primary={content.title}
                  classes={{ secondary: classes.date }}
                  secondaryTypographyProps={{ variant: 'body2' }}
                  secondary={DetermineTheDate(content.contentDate)}
                />
              </ListItem>
            );
          })}
        </List>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Have you got a call to `createMuiTheme` anywhere in your project? (This may be unrelated, but I was wondering if one of the Typography types had become mapped to `body` somehow)

Comment: Hi Matt - I do have createMuiTheme! Interesting idea. Are you able to expand on this at all? What would I be looking for? Would it be component="body" or something? I'll have a search for that, but please do let me know if you had something else in mind. Thanks so much for this clue!

Comment: I've just searched for component="body" and nothing's coming up, but this does sound like a promising idea.

Comment: Can you post the code of your `createMuiTheme`? You may want to also post the component this error is occurring within

Comment: Thanks Matt - I've added the code where I think this error is occurring (ListItemText)

Comment: If you change the "body2" to something else does the error go away?